# Make Recursive Function Functional in Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, encryption, functional-programming

I am implementing a recursive encryption for Javascript objects but the solution I came up with is non-functional. This has caused some weird errors as it manipulates the object directly. Is there any way to make this functional (return a new encypted object)?

I am at a loss on how to make this stay recursive and at the same time return a new object (functional). Specifically this is `encryptObject(dd)`

```
class Security {
  static encryptText = (text) => {
    //function to encrypt text/strings
  };
  static encryptObject(dd) {
    try {
      for (let d in dd) {
        if (!dd[d]) {
          continue;
        } else if (typeof dd[d] !== "object") {
          dd[d] = this.encryptText(dd[d]);
        } else {
          this.encryptObject(dd[d]);
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message + `error encrypting`);
    }
  }
const data = {dog:"john", cat:"anders", weapons:{laser:"3",sword:"1"}}
Security.encrypt(data)
```

I would like to call the function like this instead

```
const data = {dog:"john", cat:"anders", weapons:{laser:"3",sword:"1"}}
const encryptedData = Security.encrypt(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create and return a new object instead?

```
static encryptObject(objectToEncrypt) {
    try {
        const newObj = {};
        for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(objectToEncrypt)) {
            if (!value) {
                newObj[key] = value;
            } else if (typeof value !== "object") {
                newObj[key] = this.encryptText(value);
            } else {
                newObj[key] = this.encryptObject(value);
            }
        }
        return newObj;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e.message + `error encrypting`);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to write this is to base it on a `map` function which handles arrays and objects.  With this, and a simple identity function `(x) => x`, we can write this as

```js
const encryptObj = (o) =>
  (typeof o == 'object' ? map (encryptObj) : typeof o == 'string' ? encryptText : x => x) (o)
```

Based on whether we have an object, a string, or something else, we choose to either recursively map the result over the children, call the text encryption, or return the value unchanged.  Using a simple `rot13` function as a dummy text encryption we might write a plain function like this:

```js
const map = (fn) => (o) => Array .isArray (o) 
  ? o .map (fn) 
  : Object .fromEntries (Object .entries (o) .map (([k, v]) => [k, encryptObj (v)]))

// simple rot13
const encryptText = (cs) => [...cs] .map ((c, i, _, cc = cs.charCodeAt (i)) => cc > 64 && cc <= 91 ? String .fromCharCode (65 + ((cc - 52) % 26)) : cc > 96 && cc <= 123 ? String .fromCharCode (97 + ((cc - 84) % 26)) : c) .join ('')

const encryptObj = (o) =>
  (typeof o == 'object' ? map (encryptObj) : typeof o == 'string' ? encryptText : x => x) (o)

console .log (encryptObj ({
  a: 'foo',
  b: ['bar', 'baz', 'qux'],
  c: false,
  d: {
    e: {
      f: {
        g: {
          h: 42,
          i: 'CORGE',
          j: {
            k: 'Grault'
          }
        }
      },
      l: 99
    }
  }
}))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

And of course you can make this a static function of your class by sprinkling in some `this`s around the code.